# Mapkit Callout Accessory Button Activation

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I am using MapKit to display a map with many annotations. Each of these annotations has a callout with a UIButton. Most everything works properly, but any time there is an annotation behind the UIButton, it becomes impossible to activate it. I want the UIButton to be activatable regardless of background annotations. Is there a way to ignore the annotations directly behind the callout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an appropriate workaround to this issue:

```
(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
[view.superview bringSubviewToFront:view];
}
```

https://github.com/danielbarela/ios-map-callout-test/issues/1